# Is ASP.NET MVC definition of an AJAX success to narrow? how do i deal with other status codes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using `Ajax.BeginForm(...` in asp.net MVC 2.0
I would like to return HTTP status codes from my controller.
For example:

- 400 (validation error)
- 200 (if everything is OK)

I would like to use `new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetID="ajax-form", OnSuccess="...", OnFailure="..."}` to handle these scenarios, however If I return a statuscode of 400 the UpdateTarget does not update my html.

Is there a way to have this update occur for "failures" as well as successes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, servers don't return meaningful content for 4** errors. When they do, browsers don't tend to bother to display it. So, no, I don't think MVC is being overly finicky here.

If you think 400 is the right response from your server, then your choices are to use `$.ajax()` instead of `Html.BeginForm` or to handle `OnFailure`.

Comment: Yes, I am using the http status code to convey meaning from the server to the client (this is their intent after-all) ... How would I handle OnFailure to show the HTML ?

Comment: Something along the lines of: `<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("JsonTest", new AjaxOptions() {OnFailure = "function(data) { $("#ajax-form").html(data.get_response().get_responseData());" })) { %>` You'll have to fiddle with this; I generally use the `$.ajax` method myself.